# How to create database in Redis

Tags: asp.net, .net, .net-core, redis, stackexchange.redis

**I am new to Redis and trying to create a new database. Also, How to write a connecting string to Redis database with C#.net? Please somebody help me how to implement this.**

Answer (score 0):

In general, all use [StackExchange.Redis](https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/), you will find all you need in documentation